# Are all local classes and all anonymous classes also inner classes?

Tags: java, inner-classes, local-class

This question is mostly about proper Java terminology.

I am making the distinction between an **inner class**, which is tied to instance of its enclosing scope, and an non-inner, **nested static class** which is independent of an enclosing scope instance.

```
public class Example {
 class Inner {
     void f1() {System.out.println(Example.this); } // Inner class can access Example's this
 }
 static class StaticClass {
     void f1() {System.out.println(this); } // Static nested class - Only its own this
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 }
 void f1() {
     int local=0;
     class Local {
         void f2() {
             System.out.println(Example.this); // Local class - can access Example.this
             System.out.println(local); // can access local
         }
     }
     Runnable r = new Runnable() { 
         @Override
        public void run() {
             System.out.println(Example.this); // Anonymous local class can access Example.this
             System.out.println(local); // can access local 
        }
     };
 }
}
```

Is this the proper terminology and as follows, are all local classes and all anonymous classes also inner classes?

Comment: [JLS 8.1.3. Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) *"An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly static. An inner class is one of the following:

    a member class that is not explicitly or implicitly static (§8.5);

    a local class that is not implicitly static (§14.3);

    an anonymous class (§15.9.5)"* and more explaining which classes are implicitly static (check the link)

Comment: The Java [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) tutorial provides another review of the terminology: A **nested class** is "a class within another class". Also: "Nested classes are divided into two categories: non-static and static. Non-static nested classes are called **inner classes**. Nested classes that are declared static are called **static nested classes**." Classes which are "defined in a block" are called **local classes**.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Java Language Specification:

- An anonymous class is always an inner class (§8.1.3); it is never static (§8.1.1, §8.5.1). ([15.9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5))
- All local classes are inner classes (§8.1.3).  ([14.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3))

Comment: @user16320675 Since your comment proves further research than mine, I encourage you to post your own answer, and get the voting for it.

Answer (score 1):

- A nested class is any class whose declaration occurs within the body of another class or interface declaration. A nested class may be a member class, a local class , or an anonymous class.
- Inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly static. Inner class can refer to enclosing class instances, local variables, and type variables.
- Local class and anonymous class can'not be static so they are inner classes.

Thus, `class Inner` is nested, member and inner,
`static class StaticClass` is nested, member but not inner as it is explicitly static.